# How CompletableFuture supplyAsyncmethod() works in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous

here is example of error handling in completableFuture
https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture

```
CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture  
  =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      if (name == null) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Computation error!");
      }
      return "Hello, " + name;
  }).handle((s, t) -> s != null ? s : "Hello, Stranger!");
```

As handle() method will take BiFunction as paremeter, my question is how supplyAsync is passing that parameter to handle(). I tried to look into the source code but didnt manage to find.

And would it be to possible to demonstrate it with some simple example how function is passed from one method to another when method are chained with dot

firstMehtod(..).secondMethod(Fuction);

Comment: Whether you chain method invocations or not, is irrelevant. You can write `CompletableFuture<String> firstFuture =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { if (name == null) { throw new RuntimeException("Computation error!"); } return "Hello, " + name; }); CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = firstFuture.handle((s, t) -> s != null ? s : "Hello, Stranger!");` instead. It makes no difference. The `supplyAsync` does not pass anything to `handle` as the `supplyAsync` method does not invoke `handle`. It’s *not* different to `new StringBuilder().append(x).append(y)`.

Comment: Thanks, now its bit more clear. As supplyAsync() is async, what will happen after supplyAsync execution -  will Java wait till supplyAsync() is complete and only then move to handle() or handle() will be executed while supplyAsync() is still processing?

Comment: Don’t mix the method invocations with the evaluation of the lambda expression bodies. The methods `supplyAsync` and `handle` are executed one after the other as with any other chained method invocation. The `Supplier` is evaluated asynchronously, i.e. in a worker thread. Its completion may trigger the evaluation of the `BiFunction`, within the same worker thread or a different worker thread. It’s even possible that the `BiFunction` will be evaluated within the `handle` method if the previous stage has been completed already.

Comment: Keep in mind that you also can write your code as `Supplier<String> supplier = () -> { if (name == null) { throw new RuntimeException("Computation error!"); } return "Hello, " + name; };
BiFunction<? super String, Throwable, ? extends String> biFunction = (s, t) -> s != null ? s : "Hello, Stranger!";
CompletableFuture<String> firstStage = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier);
CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = firstStage.handle(biFunction);`

Comment: Hmm interesting, but it seems that I missing knowledge how async threads works and how they trigger evaluation of functions. Can you recommend any link where I can read about it? Thanks again!

Comment: It’s not clear where we would have to start. Do you understand the following example, `Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("hello from " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); new Thread(r).start();`? Letting aside that we use a function here to create the `Runnable`, this example works the same way as in Java 1.0. The `CompletableFuture` uses a thread pool behind the scenes but that’s not important. You can use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello", r -> new Thread(r).start()).thenAccept(System.out::println);` to create a background thread the same way as in the first example.

Comment: Thanks again, now more understandable, but I think I need to take some full course about async to be able to write something similar on my own. Lots of abstraction going on inside the supplyAsync method, but in general I got the idea.